# code errors copying from a book

Tags: java, android, code-generation

The code comes from "Hello Android"  Page47.

I am using 1.6 since that is what the book is written for.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

e1  @Override
e2  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState),
    setContentView(R.layout.main),
    // Set up click listeners for all the buttons
```

error message  e1

> the annotation @override is dissallowed for this location

error message  e2

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced    construct(s)
>     - Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
>     - Syntax error on token ")", = expected

I have no idea whats wrong.  The code is identical to the code in the book.  I'm sure.  TIA

Comment: Can you edit the question to get the code to be formatted better?

Comment: One thing I notice: The end of your lines of code have commas `,` instead of semicolons `;`

Comment: Yeah, it's far faster (and less frustrating) to download the code samples from the book's web site rather than typing it all out! :)

Comment: Eclipse asked for , not ; so I changed them.

Comment: Eclipse only told you to change them to commas because the preceding code is using the incorrect syntax (as mentioned in my answer).  Eclipse therefore can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, are you sure the book is written for Java 1.6?  I'm pretty sure Android is designed for 1.5 compatibility.

Anyway, the reason for both errors would appear to be that you have placed the `onCreate` method outside of a class body.

Between the `import` statements and the first comment, there should be a class declaration like:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
```

Comment: and furthermore the class you plan to extend (say it's `Activity` here) must have a method named `onCreate` with an identical signature to override.

Comment: The book cover says 1.5 & 1.6.  The public class didn't help.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm probably thinking of building the Android platform itself, which is (was?) 1.5 only.  Anyway, just copying and pasting what I wrote above won't fix the code.. there's braces required at the start and end of the class etc.  It might be beneficial to look at some Java tutorials before starting out with Android.

Comment: The book wasn't clear as where to put that statement.  I downloaded the code.  But I am only using it when I can't figure out what is going on.  I want to learn Droid Java.  Thanks.  I reloaded the SDK.  It works now.  Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Download the code from [Hello Android's Official Website](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/eband2/hello-android) to get a for-sure working version. You can also check the errata.